# what's wrong with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB R2010b and I can't understand what is wrong with matlab...

```
>> SSS = simpleseries_dataset;

>> [X,T] = SSS;

>> ???Too many output arguments.
```

but next code is good:

```
>> [X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit more...

Comment: You need to show how X and T are defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab "Index Exceeds Matrix Dimensions" neural network function error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080079/matlab-index-exceeds-matrix-dimensions-neural-network-function-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`simpleseries_dataset` is a function; functions can have multiple outputs - if you type `edit simpleseries_dataset`, you can see the function definition:

```
function [inputs,targets] = simpleseries_dataset
```

When you run your first line of code, you have a single output variable - so `inputs` is stored in `SSS` and `targets` is discarded; assigning the output of a multiple output function to a single variable is equivalent to doing:

```
[SSS, ~] = simpleseries_dataset;
```

so if you want to keep both of the output values from `simpleseries_dataset`, you have to call the function with two outputs.