# Can someone help Train this Neural Network in Matlab and check what I am doing?

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, neural-network

Firstly - this is how my data looks :

```
in1 = [a vector of [5189,1]]
in2 = [a vector of [5189,1]]
in3 = [a vector of [5189,1]]

out = [a vector of [5189,1]]
```

What I'm trying to do is predict the output using the 3 inputs/

Now, I've been training a radial basis network doing the follow steps :

```
net = newrbe([in1';in2';in3'], out', 100);
```

And then obtaining the predictions using a testing set with the `sim` function. Firstly, is this the correct way to do what I am supposed to be doing? I'm getting a good answer / prediction, hence I assumed it is fine.

Now, I wanted to train a recurrent neural network using the same methodology. I did the following as per the manual at : http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/layrecnet.html

So ,

```
net = layrecnet(1:2,100);
```

and then I simply did `[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,C);`

where `X = [in1';in2';in3']`
and   `C = out';`

And I got the error :

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Hence, using the answer at ["Index Exceeds Matrix Dimensions" neural network function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080079/index-exceeds-matrix-dimensions-neural-network-function-error)

I did `X =  num2cell([in1',in2',in3']);`
  and `C = num2cell(out');`

And then tried the `preparets` function again to get :

```
Error using preparets (line 161)
The number of input signals does not match network's non-feedback inputs.
```

OR

```
Error using network/train (line 293)
Number of inputs does not match net.numInputs.
```

Can someone teach / explain to me just how should I get this thing done? I have a decent idea of what a recurrent neural network is, however this problem seems to be a matlab problem. Please tell me just how should I give the inputs / feedbacks etc? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ***layrecnet*** and others neural networks that demands ***cell*** input format, you can use the command ***con2seq(in)*** and ***con2seq(out)*** [no mater the dimension of the vectors in and out]. This command will convert you input *NxM* in a *1xM* cell arrange or so.

Reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/con2seq.html